# How to pass the dictonary object to Django-rest-framework with double quote by http.request's json parameter?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I got this error message on Django-rest-framework.

```
JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"
}
```

Its cause must be single quote, but I passed the json datavia http.request method, like as below.

```
r = requests.patch('http://localhost:8000/api/xxxx,headers=self.headers, json=payload)
```

the payload is dictionary.

```
id = 111
paylod = {resultid:{"data":"abc","data2","def"}}
```

How should I handle this? I appreciate the advise!

Answer (score 0):

Add double quotes to `resultid` in payload dict

```
paylod = {"resultid":{"data":"abc","data2","def"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks shaik moeed,
I found my mistake.
I checked the functionality on django-rest-framework with raw input form,
But in this time, I use json parameter on http.request, thus I do not need consider single quote or double quote.